# Can I define a PHP class that can only see variables passed to it and only default php functions?

Tags: php

Can I define a PHP class that can only see variables passed to it and only default php functions? I need it to limit what functions my employees use.

Comment: Wait what? Why do you want to limit a developer from properly using a programming language?

Comment: Please, clarify and make an example

Comment: If you don't trust your developers to write good code, find new developers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs more clarification. The only real life scenario which I can relate to, from your question is when multiple developers are working on various modules of the software and you want to stop them from getting in each others ways. The solution for that would be using Namespaces while making the classes, and using private functions and variables rather than making everything public. Check out the references below for an idea.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php